# I don't understand what's going on with SBC

Tags: assembly, 6502

I've just started to learn 6502 because I want to create an Atari 2600 game.

I have tried this code:

```
LDA #$01
STA $01
LDX #$02
TXA
SBC $01
BRK
```

And I get the value A=$00, and flags Z and C set to 1. But I think the value in A must be $01.

If I change the values because I probably doing wrong the subtract:

```
LDA #$02
STA $01
LDX #$01
TXA
SBC $01
BRK
```

I get the value A=$fe, and flag N set to 1.

What's happening?

Comment: I recommend [this tutorial on 6502 arithmetic](http://www.6502.org/tutorials/vflag.html#2.4).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SBC is subtract with carry. If C is 0 prior to the SBC instruction, it subtracts one more than you expect.

Put SEC before the SBC.

Answer (score 2):

The carry flag is an input to the `SBC` instruction, set it to 1 perform a subtraction without borrow.

Answer (score 2):

The instruction set is clear here: http://www.obelisk.me.uk/6502/reference.html#SBC . It says:

> This instruction subtracts the contents of a memory location to the
>   accumulator together **with the not of the carry bit**

To avoid the problem, always use `SEC` instruction before `SBC` as below:

```
LDA #$01
STA $01
LDX #$02
TXA
SEC        ; for correct next subtraction with SBC
SBC $01
BRK
```

Comment: My problem was that I didn't understand what the documentation you have linked says about SBC. Thanks.